# How can I avoid code duplication by using OOP or SOLID principles?

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following class and interface for him:

```
public class A // int wrapper
{
    private int _a;

    public A(int a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }
}

interface IProgram
{
    int a();

    A b();
}

public class Program : IProgram
{
    public int a()
    {
       int b = 0;
       b++;
       return b;
    }

    public A b()
    {
        int b = 0;
        b++;
        return new A(b);
    }
}
```

Two methods do the same thing: just increase `b`.

How can I avoid code duplication and change my interface?

Comment: I think first() and second() should be a() and b() respectively

Comment: sounds like something for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also, _a = a; should be a = _a; ?

Comment: Not sure you really want generics here?

Comment: Why don't you just implement `b` in terms of `a`? i.e. `return new A(b())`. Then it can just be an extension method on `IProgram`.

Comment: The methods do not "do the same thing:"

Comment: @OguzOzgul Thanks, edit

Comment: And in this case you don't really need `b()` because you can just write `A a = program.a()` and use the implicit conversion operator from `int` on `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a private method which iterates int b and returns it, then call that method from a() and b()